# bower install fails silently on any package

Tags: bower

I can install Bower and it seems just fine via npm. I create a bower.json file using bower init, and add dependencies. Then when I use bower install, literally nothing happens in the terminal. I can use bower update to install packages, but bower install does not work and I cannot get any error to produce, even with --verbose. I've included bower.json below:

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "authors": [
    "AJ"
  ],
  "main": "index.html",
  "license": "private",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#~0.3.0",
    "core-menu": "Polymer/core-menu",
    "core-ajax": "Polymer/core-ajax"
  }
}
```

edit: using 1.3.3, but I've reproduced this using 1.3.2 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `bower_components` directory and running `bower install` again.

**Edit:**
This is also related to a circular dependency in Polymer see: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1324#issuecomment-44436595

Comment: This fixed it for bower install for dependencies already in bower.json, but does not fix the use case of installing a singular package via cli, ex. "bower install jquery".