# Error installing core-elements and polymer-ui-elements

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I was installing the polymer on my windows 8 pc by taking tutorials from [tutplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-polymer-to-create-web-components--cms-20475). I was able to install `Polymer/platform` and `Polymer/polymer` using bower.

Now, I wanted to install the `core-elements` and `polymer-ui-elements` but every time when I do:

```
bower install Polymer/core-elements
bower install Polymer/polymer-ui-elements
```

The command line hangs up for a minute and then gives the error:

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: I've also had issues with bower hanging in the last couple days. bower version 1.3.1, node v0.10.26

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917177/bower-install-fails-silently-on-any-package. Also make sure your bower is up to date 1.3.3, the memory issue was fixed.

Comment: I have the latest version and followed few other questions too which were based on node js. But still this error is popping up.

Comment: Bower 1.3.4 is out. Can you update and check that this is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This is from [Installing Polymer through bower freezes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933626/installing-polymer-through-bower-freezes/23987277#23987277)

======================

according to http://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1324 there is a workaround.

edit bower.json by adding in a line so the dependency area looks like this

dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#~0.3.1", 
    "core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements"
  }
then run $ bower update

you can add other packages, too.

I'm actually brand new to polymer (had trouble installing it, as you can imagine) so I'm not positive this works.